# \settolength issue

Tags: lengths

I want a horizontal length to have the same length as the word "physique".

This is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\newlength{\longueurperso}
\setlength{\longueurperso}{30pt}

\newlength{\motphysique}
\settolength{\motphysique}{physique}

\begin{document}
Bonjour! 

Voici un espace horizontal de \hspace{\longueurperso} 30 points. 

La \hspace{\motphysique} est une science pure.
\end{document}
```

When I compile, here is what I get:

[image]

What's wrong? I tried to put the lines

```
\newlength{\motphysique}
\settolength{\motphysique}{physique}
```

after the `\begin{document}` and it's not working better.

Comment: Use `\settowidth`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\setlength` expects lengths to be given explicitly like `30pt`. You have two options. First use `\settowidth` as mentioned by  Yiannis Lazarides: `\settowidth{\motphysique}{physique}`. Second, if you want to stick with `\setlength`, load `calc` package and define `\setlength{\motphysique}{\widthof{physique}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}    %% provides \widthof
\newlength{\longueurperso}
\setlength{\longueurperso}{30pt}

\newlength{\motphysique}
%\settowidth{\motphysique}{physique}
\setlength{\motphysique}{\widthof{physique}}

\begin{document}
Bonjour!

Voici un espace horizontal de \hspace{\longueurperso} 30 points.

La \hspace{\motphysique} est une science pure.
\end{document}
```

[image]